# How to pass struct with array attribute from Java to SQL stored procedure?

Tags: java, sql, stored-procedures, jdbc, oracle11g

I have some types in Oracle.

```
create or replace
TYPE r_telefone_cand AS OBJECT (
    candidato NUMBER(10,0),
    telefone VARCHAR2(15)
);

create or replace TYPE t_telefone_cand AS TABLE OF r_telefone_cand;

create or replace
TYPE r_candidato AS OBJECT (
    codigo NUMBER(10,0),
    rg VARCHAR2(15),
    cpf NUMBER(15,0),
    nome VARCHAR2(50),
    telefone t_telefone_cand,
);
```

And I have a procedure insert_candidato that parameter candidato is IN r_candidato

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE insert_candidato(
    candidato IN r_candidato
) AS ...
```

But I don't know how to pass the parameter candidato with the collection telefone.

Please, help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a try using JPublisher of Oracle.. !

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10500_01/java.920/a96658/intro.htm

It helps in interacting with user defined DB objects through Java.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SQLData to map a java class to an oracle User Defined type. Check out the docs at http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/SQLData.html

In your case you'd need two types to match the db types.